# Frames with multiple background images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use multiple background images to obtain this result on a liquid width div:

[image]

I have split the image in three parts:

[image]

And I'm trying to style the div like this:

```
        height: 14px;
        background-image: url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-l.gif), 
            url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-bg.gif),
            url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-r.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
        background-position: left, center, right;
```

But the right margin doesn't work and so I have this instead:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GSxuH.gif]

Any help? Thanks

**EDIT**
Fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/J5Tsa/

**SOLVED**
Seems like it is a z-index problem among the images. Declaring the right margin *before* the repeated one solved the problem.

Comment: any chance of a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Is `workspace-pre-hr-bg.gif` a set width?  If your div isn't a set width, you'll need to take that into account.

Comment: alan: that is the 1px width image that i repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that images are stacked according to the order in which they are specified in the `background-image` property. So my theory is that `workspace-pre-hr-r.gif` is being displayed underneath `workspace-pre-hr-bg.gif`.

Try this...

```
background-image: url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-l.gif), 
  url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-r.gif),
  url(static/img/workspace-pre-hr-bg.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-position: left, right, center;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 supports `border-image` rule, which accomplishes what you want, should you be willing to give up compatibility with earlier CSS versions and user agents. The syntax looks much leaner and easier to read:

```
<div style="border-width: 25px; border-image: url(http://codebrief.com/old/uploads/2011/11/aqua_bg.png) 25 25 25 25 repeat; background-color: #00e0a0; background-clip: padding-box;">Hello World!</div>​
```

I wrote and saved it at http://jsfiddle.net/Wnq3z/

I simply Googled and found a solution which I credit to http://codebrief.com/2011/11/two-game-changing-css-3-features/ after recalling I read something about this being present in CSS 3.

Comment: this is the optimal solution, thanks, but multiple bg images, while pretty new as well, have a much better support among browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a Fiddle, i can suggest you to use the center image only, 
rounding up its borders with something like:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
```

EDIT: as a note, border-radius is born to bypass the [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique...